# Memorate jQuery variable into php variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php script that contains a jQuery script too:

```
<?php
echo "<img class='PrevIMG' onclick='ShowURL(event)' src= 'http://imageURL'/>
         <script>
            function ShowURL(event){
                var im = event.target.src;
                alert(im);
            }
         </script>"
?>
```

I echo an image and a jQuery script with php and memorate image's URL into `im` jQuery variable when I click it.
I want to memorate that `im` variable into a php variable so that I can POST/GET it.

Comment: You have to either reload the page or use ajax to send the data back to the server, as that's where PHP happens.